# PROBLEM WITH NEW GUI WALLET

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon

monero wallet problems.

I dsisnstalled and re-installed monero, I had previously sent moneros to the 3 address created, which now I no longer see and there is only one. how do I get that address back?